# Angular 2 Router blows up when module is loaded externally

Tags: angular, systemjs

I am using a ng2 router and if I am using an internal module (same file) all is good... but if I load it externally the Router does not work and I get an error from Angular about issues with router instantiation... I appreciate any help, I shared the code here: https://github.com/born2net/ng2RouterProblem/blob/master/app/bootstrap.ts

I am suspecting something with system.js config as before I used to transpile to typescript in the browser (default type 'ts' system config) but now that I moved to .js as default extension everything blows up :(

tx again for reading,

Sean

Answer (score 0):

well I think I found the issue, I compiled with -target es6 and now changed to -target es5 and all works... woooff.... 5 hours on this one, hopefully it helps someone else...!